# Add version to Tomcat path

Tags: tomcat, version

I have a Tomcat application called

```
app-0.0.war
```

I have a location (`/a/b/c`) on my server which if I deploy the application to

```
/a/b/c/app-0.0.war
```

I can access the application at

```
http://some.url:port/app-0.0/
```

I would like to instead access it at

```
http://some.url:port/v0.0/app
```

Are there any easy ways to achieve this? Something like deploy to

```
/a/b/c/v0.0/app.war
```

Which doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#` mark gets treated as if it is a folder marker so deploy to

```
/a/b/c/v0.0#app.war
```

And the application will be available at

```
http://some.url:port/v0.0/app
```